Can we force ForAll to run in sequential order
I am reading this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/author-advanced-formulas-powerapps/4-forall-funct...
and it mentioned that ForAll is not guarantee to run in sequential order. for example if we have this formula, to loop through all groups >> all groups planners >> all planners tasks, as follow:-
ClearCollect(finalResult,{PlanTitle:"",TaskTitle:"",Status:"",AssignedToUserId:"",DueDate:"",TaskID:"",PlannerID:"",GroupID:""});
Clear(colRelatedGroupsIds);
Clear(colRelatedPlanners);
Clear(colRelatedPlannerTasks);

ClearCollect(colTeamSitesItem,Filter('Team Sites',1=1));
ClearCollect(colAllGroups,Office365Groups.ListGroups().value);
ForAll(colAllGroups As group,
ForAll(colTeamSitesItem As i2,

If(Lower(group.displayName)=Lower(i2.'Team Site Name'),
Collect(colRelatedGroupsIds,group.id))));

ForAll(colRelatedGroupsIds As group,
Collect(colRelatedPlanners,
Planner.ListGroupPlans(group.Value).value);

ForAll(colRelatedPlanners As planner,
Collect(colRelatedPlannerTasks,
Planner.ListTasksV3(planner.id,group.Value).value);
ForAll(colRelatedPlannerTasks As task,
ForAll(task._assignments As taskAssignment,
Patch(finalResult,Defaults(finalResult),
{
PlanTitle:planner.title,
AssignedToUserId:taskAssignment.userId,
Status:If(Text(task.percentComplete)="100","Completed",
   If(Text(task.percentComplete)="50","In Progress",
  If(Text(task.percentComplete)="0","Not Started"))),
TaskTitle:task.title,
DueDate:Text(DateTimeValue(task.dueDateTime), "dd/mm/yyyy"),
TaskID:task.id,
GroupID:group.Value,
PlannerID:planner.id
})


));RemoveIf(colRelatedPlannerTasks,true));RemoveIf(colRelatedPlanners,true));

and for it to work well, i need to run the formulas inside the ForAll in a sequential order to build the collection and remove its items, after each iteration, i do not want to have a case where the collection hold values from more than one iteration at a certain point in time, is this possible and how?
thanks

I've only glanced at your formula, so I definitely don't fully understand it, but is this something that could be done with a Power Automate flow that is executed from your canvas app? This would give you greater control over the parallelism and order it is processed.

@user79408 i tried to do this on power automate, and call this flow inside power apps, the issue is that the process will take more than 2 minutes so the flow is going to fail,, so i have to do it inside power apps

Is it important to get the output from your formula as soon as it's completed? If not, I'd still try using Power Automate with a "Respond to Power Apps" action somewhere at the beginning of your flow. I am doing something similar with an app that has a Move file flow. It can take hours for the flow to run but from the Power Apps users' perspective, they press the button, get a message informing that the process is underway and then the flow runs in the background. May not be suitable for your use case, but I just wanted to highlight that there may be other ways to achieve the same goal.

As far as I know (and what I have always done) is to set [Concurrency] On, and [Degrees of Parallelism] to 1, under the [ForAll] actions settings:


OP is trying to do it in "Power Apps", not in "Power Automate" flows.

@GaneshSanap-MVP thanks for your comment, did you ever face the same issue as mine? to force ForAll to run in sequential order?

@Mike Collins i am asking how to do this inside Power App and not Power Automate

Check if it helps in any way: https://www.iammancat.dev/2022/08/sequential-concurrent-forall-in-power-apps/
